# dependent ng-model in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I am having two select controls. based on one select control second select control should be populated just like on country  select state will fill in second select control.

my code is like -

```
<select ng-model="parentModel" id="ddlState">
<option value="mp"> mp </option>
<option value="mh"> mh </option>
</select>

<select ng-model="childModel" id="ddlcity" ng-options = "a as a for a in $scope.coll[parentModel]">
</select>
```

and script is -

```
<script>

    var arr=  new Array();
    arr["mp"] = ['map1','map2'];
    arr["mh"] = ['mh11','mh2'];


    myapp = angular.module("myapp", []);

    myapp.controller("MyController", function ($scope) {

        $scope.parentModel = "mh";
        //$scope.childModel="pune";
        $scope.coll=arr;
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea - a couple changes though:

JavaScript doesnt have associative arrays, so use an object:

```
$scope.arr = {};
$scope.arr.mp = ["map1", "map2"];
$scope.arr.mh = ["mh11", "mh2"];
```

No need to reference `$scope` in your `ng-options`

```
ng-options = "a as a for a in arr[parentModel]"
```

Not sure what `$scope.coll` was meant to be...but it's not needed to make a dependent `select` in your case.